# Stream music on Android to Desktop speakers

Tags: audio, music, streaming

The **canonical** location for my music collection is the Android phone (synced from Mac at work), and I have a Windows PC at home connected to the speaker system. Is it possible to play the music on Android, but stream (via bluetooth, wifi or USB) the audio to these speakers (via the PC)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. No additional soft or hardware is required. On Android 4.4.2 and Windows XP:

1. Enable Bluetooth on both devices
2. Make sure under Windows' Bluetooth Configuration -> Local Services you have the 'Headset' service set to 'Automatic startup'
3. Connect the devices (using a pass-phrase if required)
4. Check on Android that 'Media audio' is enabled for the connected PC
5. Play some music, enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Get a male-to-male 3.5 mm audio cable. Connect one end to your phone's audio jack and the other one to your PC's microphone jack.

Now here comes the tricky part:

1. In the notification area, right-click the speaker icon. Click "Playback Devices".
2. In the Dialogue Box, right-click "Speakers -> Set as Default Device". If there is already a green tick on the speaker icon, move to step 3.
3. If you have a laptop then (A), or a desktop then (B) :

   (A) Remove the cable you just connected. Now click on the "Recording" tab. See, there's a Mic which has a green tick. Don't interfere with this thing. Now the second one is a mic which is disconnected and has a red mark. Now connect the cable. It will show ready. Now double-click it. In the popup, click the "Listen" tab. Check the "Listen to this Device". In the "Playback through this device dropdown, select Speakers. Now click Apply. Your computer might now start producing awkward sounds, to adjust, click the "Levels" tab. Now adjust the Microphone volume and Microphone boost to the desired amount to remove any sort of noise.

   (B) If you have a desktop, all the steps are the same as a laptop except the microphone selection. In the recording devices menu, only one microphone should be there. So it is easy to find that. Do all the next steps as a laptop.

   **NOTE:** If you can't see your device, right-click and tick "Show disabled devices" and "Show disconnected devices". If your device is disabled, enable it first.
4. Now, play any audio of your choice on the phone to get the desired output.

   **P.S.**: Any device with a 3.5 mm audio output can be used as a source.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in Windows XP and 7. It will stream all audio from the phone- apps, games, etc. You do not need any additional software, just Bluetooth connectivity on the PC.

AirDroid lets you access your device, including streaming music, over WiFi via a web browser.

You could also just plug your phone into a USB to your PC, and play the music on the PC with MusicBee or any other media player.

Comment: Please consider adding details as to how.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't found a solution yet, I would recommend an app called [Soundwire](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.georgie.SoundWireFree)

Comment: AFAIK this only goes the other way around (i.e. from PC to android).

Comment: I think AllStream does this.