# Can we stream Pocketcast to the pc?

Tags: music, streaming, podcast

I just want to listen to the podcasts through my PC speakers when ever im close to the pc. How can. I do this?

Comment: Can't you open the podcast from the PC?

Comment: Yes i can but when i have podcasts downloaded on my phone i dont want to download again in the pc. Have limited bandwidth

Comment: In that case a general solution might help, see http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17701/stream-music-on-android-to-desktop-speakers